# Strange Problems With Python After Upgrading to OS X Mavericks

Tags: readline, osx-mavericks

After upgrading my OS X Lion to Mavericks, I've encountered with strange problems. 
At first, It gave me *segmentation fault* or *bus error*. After searching for a bit I've noticed that it's related to the *readline* library. The solution was described by *bugs.python.org*:

```
curl -O http://bugs.python.org/file32324/patch_readline_issue_18458.sh 
openssl sha1 patch_readline_issue_18458.sh # the digest should be 7cb0ff57820a027dd4ca242eb2418930f8f46b4c 
sudo sh ./patch_readline_issue_18458.sh
```

This will disable the *readline* library. The errors are gone now but I have another problem. In Python shell when I press arrow keys (up, down, left or right) it gives me these: `^[[A`, `[[C^`, `^[[B`, `^[[D`. I think the problem is still related to the *readline* library but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no authority on the guts of Python, so take my advice with caution. But, having encountered the same problem after the Mavericks upgrade (and using Python 2.7), I just did a

```
easy_install readline
```

at the command line, and everything seems to be working again. No more segmentation error, and arrow keys in the Python shell appear to be functioning normally.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. :)
P.S. : It must be executed with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

The (brand new) Python 3.3.3rc1  fixes the SegFault problem.

It's  here:   http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/

Comment: Yes, but I want to use Python 2.7 as I'm used to this version not the Python 3.x.x.