# Python quit unexpectedly

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

Can anybody help with this? Whenever I try to launch tkinter, i get this report:

> Process:               Python [1106] Path:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Identifier:            org.python.python Version:               3.5.1
>   (3.5.1) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:
>   Python [1036] Responsible:           Python [1036] User ID:
>   501
>
> Date/Time:             2016-04-28 00:14:59.804 -0500 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1713) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   8A5EA9E5-B94F-6C3F-2F7E-EC33C5FA8E26
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 4900 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5afffff8
>
> VM Regions Near 0x7fff5afffff8:
>       mapped file            000000010a37f000-000000010a409000 [  552K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Fonts/Monaco.dfont
>   --> 
>       __UNIXSTACK            00007fff5b000000-00007fff5c000000 [ 16.0M] rw-/rwx SM=COW 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling python for your version of mac osx?i know this problem was on osx 10.9  as detailed [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723073/strange-problems-with-python-after-upgrading-to-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: Had to debug my code. Also had to update the tlc version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python **quit unexpectedly** when running the code below on my Mac (OS X Yosemite):

```
root.config(menu_Bar = file_Menu)


# Tkinter GUI Menu

from tkinter import *

### Functions ###

# Do Nothing
def do_Nothing():
    print('I just did... nothing')



### Create tkinter window ###

# Create Window
root = Tk() 



#### Creating the Menu(s) ###

# Create the Menu Bar
menu_Bar = Menu(master = root)

# Create File Menu
file_Menu = Menu(master = menu_Bar)



### Displaying the Menu(s) ###

# Display Menu Bar
root.config(menu = menu_Bar)

# Display File Menu
menu_Bar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file_Menu)




### File Menu Properties ####

# New
file_Menu.add_command(label = 'New', command = do_Nothing)

# Open
file_Menu.add_command(label = 'Open', command = do_Nothing)

# Exit
file_Menu.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = root.quit) 




### Display tkinter window ###
root.mainloop()


# Display Menu Bar
root.config(menu = menu_Bar)
```

The issue that made Python ***quit unexpectedly*** was that instead of

```
# Display Menu Bar
root.config(menu = menu_Bar)
```

I had originally wrote something like:

```
# Display Menu Bar
root.config(myMenu = menu_Bar)
```

In addition to that, I had to update the Tlc from version ***`Apple 8.5.9`*** to ***`ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0`***. The website for this is here: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-18-0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can reinstall a corrupted Python environment like this:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force python python@2
unset PYTHONPATH
brew install python python@2
```

I had another "quit unexpectedly" issue and this resolved it for me.